# Instant failover option - pinging hostname

Tags: performance, dns, failover, instant

im new here so bear with me.

Im a trial period employee at a IT company which focuses on server solutions, failovers etc. I had a task to ping a machine through DNS, whenever machine shuts down the ping should continue (some sort of failover solution, hostname with multiple IPs like web pages and whatnot). I managed to acomplish that by having 2 IPs in DNS table in MS Server 2012 R2. When the machines switched there were dropped packets, and the whole transfer took about 30 seconds, but the task was done.

**Now comes the tricky part - now I have to come up with an instant solution.
When I ping a hostname (for example ping Test), when the first machine goes offline, the second machine should start pinging right away without any lost packets or atleast reduce failover time to 5 seconds.**

I have an understanding that there should be a overwatch system that talks with the machines and if one of them isnt talking back the system immediately ignores it. I just dont know how to do that. I have access on physical and virtual machines and servers, Mikrotik routers aswell. Every idea helps, there is no right method, i just need it to ping without interruptions when one machine fails. Tried to Google it out, but with no results.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I used the Network loadbalancing feature in Server 2012 on all clients which I needed to work. Aslong the machine is running with the client the cluster IP is active and the pinging continues. When the machine is turned off, aslong there are other machine with the network loadbalance client up the cluster ip pings.